# Parsing an XML document to get node values

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have an xml structure as below:

```
String attributesXML="<entry>
            <value>
              <List>
                <String>Rob</String>
                <String>Mark</String>
                <String>Peter</String>
                <String>John</String>
             </List>
          </value>
        </entry>"
```

I want to fetch the values Rob,Mark,Peter,John.  I can get the nodes starting from entry node(Code below). Problem is i don't know what will be the child node names under entry node. Starting from entry node i need to keep drilling down until I find the values. I have written a method getChildNodeValue() but it doesn't give me the required Output. It does print what i need but it prints some extra stuff as well. I need to return the values as a csv from this method getChildNodeValue().

Getting Entry Node:

```
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                    InputSource is = new InputSource();
                    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(attributesXML));

                    Document doc = db.parse(is);
                    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

                if(nodes.item(i).hasChildNodes()){

                    getChildNodeValue(nodes.item(i));

                }
} 


public static void getChildNodeValue(Node node) {

    System.out.println("Start Node: "+node.getNodeName());

    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
      Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);

       while(currentNode.hasChildNodes()){

           System.out.println("Current Node: "+currentNode.getNodeName());

           nodeList = currentNode.getChildNodes();

          for(int j=0;j<nodeList.getLength();j++){

              currentNode = nodeList.item(j);
              System.out.println("Node name: "+currentNode.getNodeName());
              System.out.println("Node value: "+currentNode.getTextContent());

          }

       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code. It's all over the place at the moment, making it really hard to read. Always look at the preview before you post, and ask whether that's the post *you'd* want to see if you were trying to find good questions to answer.

Comment: @Jon, I will format it. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use XStream library for xml parsing it will parse java object to xml and vice versa.
check out below link
http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html